# App runs well on emulator and fails on device

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, mediarecorder

Pretty bad to see that I developed my first app and the beta version failed to run on device. The app will basically add a picture along with text details for the same. A voice record to keep some more lively info for the same. On emulator, this is working fine, but failing on the device :-(
Please help.

here is LogCat:

```
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.tg_db1/databases/Bengalooru' 
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:2063)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1117)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1074)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:869)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at com.example.tg_db1.RegistrationAdapter.write(RegistrationAdapter.java:27)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at com.example.tg_db1.RegistrationAdapter.queryName(RegistrationAdapter.java:68)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at com.example.tg_db1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4533)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(31541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2221)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2313)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2309)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2274)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1246)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:2034)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:185)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
    06-19 18:04:33.495: E/System(31541):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

add_company.java

```
    package com.example.tg_db1;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class add_company extends Activity{
        ImageView iv;
        Button b1,b2,b3;
        EditText et1, et2;
        RegistrationAdapter adapter;
        RegistrationOpenHelper helper;

        private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
        private String logopath;
        String imgPath = null;
        private Bitmap bitmap;

        //Adding for voice record
        ImageButton play,record,stop;
        private String voicerec=null;
        MediaPlayer mp;
        MediaRecorder mr;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.add_company);

            iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
            et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

            adapter = new RegistrationAdapter(this);
            iv.setImageDrawable(null);  //Should be blank before selecting the image

            //Adding voice record
            play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Play);
            record = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Record);
            stop = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Stop);
        }

        public void browse(View v){
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            int id = v.getId();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            InputStream stream = null;

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri imgUri = data.getData();
                logopath = getPath(imgUri);

                //This block is to show the view
                    try {
                        if(bitmap != null){
                            bitmap.recycle();
                        }
                            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                            iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, true));
                        } 
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                finally{
                    if (stream != null) {
                        try {
                                stream.close();
                            } 
                        catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int col_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(col_index);
        }

        //Adding for voice record
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void submit(View v){
            String compname = et1.getText().toString();
            String address = et2.getText().toString();
            logopath = imgFilePath();
            long val = adapter.insertDetails(compname, address, logopath, voicerec);
            finish();
        }

        private String imgFilePath() {
            File imgFile = null;
            try {
                imgFile = File.createTempFile("complogo", ".png");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileOutputStream fOut = null;
            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            imgPath = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
            return imgPath;
        }

        public void reset(View v){
            et1.setText("");
            et2.setText("");
            iv.setImageDrawable(null);  //Image is removed when reset
            voicerec = null;    //Voice record path set to null
        }

        public void record(View v){
            File audioFile = null;
            try {
                audioFile = File.createTempFile("voice", ".amr");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            mr = new MediaRecorder();

            voicerec = audioFile.getAbsolutePath();
            //System.out.println("Path: "+voicerec);

            mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
            mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mr.setOutputFile(voicerec);
            try{
                mr.prepare();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(add_company.this, "Recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mr.start();
        }
        public void stop(View v){
            mr.stop();  //this is stop recording

            Toast.makeText(add_company.this, "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mr.reset();     // this is required to avoid the error:  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)
            mr.release();
        }
        public void play(View v){
            try{
                File f = new File(voicerec);
                Uri u = Uri.fromFile(f);
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(add_company.this, u);
                mp.setLooping(false);
                mp.start();
            }
            catch(RuntimeException re){
                re.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

RegistrationAdapter.java

```
    package com.example.tg_db1;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

    public class RegistrationAdapter {
        SQLiteDatabase sdb;
        RegistrationOpenHelper helper;
        Context context;

        public RegistrationAdapter(Context c){
            context = c;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public RegistrationAdapter read(){
            helper = new RegistrationOpenHelper(context, helper.DATABASE_NAME, null, helper.VERSION);
            sdb = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public RegistrationAdapter write(){
            helper = new RegistrationOpenHelper(context, helper.DATABASE_NAME, null, helper.VERSION);
            sdb = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void close(){
            if(sdb!=null)
            sdb.close();
        }


    //Addition for voice    
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public long insertDetails(String compname, String address, String complogo, String voicerec){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); 
            cv.put(helper.COMP_NAME, compname);
            cv.put(helper.COMP_ADDRESS, address);
            cv.put(helper.COMP_LOGO, complogo);
            cv.put(helper.COMP_VOICE, voicerec);
            write();
            long val = sdb.insert(helper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
            close();
            return val;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public long updateDetail(int rowID, String compname, String address, String complogo, String voicerec){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); 
            cv.put(helper.COMP_NAME, compname);
            cv.put(helper.COMP_ADDRESS, address);
            cv.put(helper.COMP_LOGO, complogo);
            cv.put(helper.COMP_VOICE, voicerec);
            write();
            long val = sdb.update(helper.TABLE_NAME, cv, helper.KEY_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
            close();
            return val;
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public Cursor queryName(){
            String[] cols = {helper.KEY_ID, helper.COMP_NAME, helper.COMP_ADDRESS, helper.COMP_LOGO, helper.COMP_VOICE};
            write();
            Cursor c = sdb.query(helper.TABLE_NAME, cols, null, null, null, null, null);
            return c;       
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public Cursor queryAll(int nameID){
            String[] cols = {helper.KEY_ID, helper.COMP_NAME, helper.COMP_ADDRESS, helper.COMP_LOGO, helper.COMP_VOICE};
            write();
            Cursor c = sdb.query(helper.TABLE_NAME, cols, helper.KEY_ID + " = " + nameID, null, null, null, null);
            return c;
        }

        public int deleteDetail(int rowID){
            write();
            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            int val = sdb.delete(helper.TABLE_NAME, helper.KEY_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
            close();
            return val;
        }

    }
```

Comment: most of the time, it's because you added something in buildpath and not in export

Comment: everytime you access the database you should open() it and then call close() after you are done.

Comment: Did you close your helper?

Comment: call close() after fetching results from queryName() and queryAll(int nameID) methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your code

```
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (sdb!= null) {
        sdb.close();
    }
```

and also close the Cursor object after using it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: When i got that error 'close() was never explicitly..' i called onDestroy() which worked for me.

Comment: as I said, it might be called very often but it is, according to the documentation, not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: @WarrenFaith its not clear that you are responsible for cleaning up in memory state when it isn't, since that happens when the process is going away.  You do need to leave the db in a recoverable state though.

Comment: @WarrenFaith - As you mentioned, there is no guarantee. So its clear for me if I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Database once in your Application class in onCreate and don't close it but close the cursor as soon as you don't need them. Keep a static reference (your `sdb` variable, for example) there and access it directly.

For example: `RegistrationAdapter.queryName()` returns a cursor. So where ever you return a cursor, check the usage and close it as soon as it is not used anymore. That should fix the issue.

Comment: When I close the cursor, I'm getting an error that I'm trying to open a closed db.

Comment: are you closing the cursor after you get the data from it? I mean not int the `queryName()` method but after that. Normally after you loop over the cursor, you should be able to close the cursor without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following methods are creating problems.

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public Cursor queryName(){
    String[] cols = {helper.KEY_ID, helper.COMP_NAME, helper.COMP_ADDRESS, helper.COMP_LOGO, helper.COMP_VOICE};
    write();
    Cursor c = sdb.query(helper.TABLE_NAME, cols, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;       
}

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public Cursor queryAll(int nameID){
        String[] cols = {helper.KEY_ID, helper.COMP_NAME, helper.COMP_ADDRESS, helper.COMP_LOGO, helper.COMP_VOICE};
        write();
        Cursor c = sdb.query(helper.TABLE_NAME, cols, helper.KEY_ID + " = " + nameID, null, null, null, null);
        return c;
    }
```

close your database and cursor you are returning after you use them.

Comment: When I close the cursor & database, getting an error that I'm trying to open a closed db. Not working that way :-(

Comment: First perform your task which you want to do, and then close them when you are done with your job.